# Speed up MySQL query when using ORDER BY and HAVING

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that has a bunch of market orders for a game.  My intent with the DB is to buy low and sell high so what I do is search for any product that I can make money off of.  I enter a starting point and a end point and then check the DB for products that are for sale at the starting location and also check the end point for any buy orders that match and have a profit.

Right now I have about 750k listings and it takes about 8 seconds to process the query.  It took less time when I had less rows.  I will probably have over a 5 million entries once the database is full and I need to figure how how to speed up my query.  I know when I take out the HAVING and ORDER BY, it takes about .25/s to query.  Is there another way to do this in mySQL or should I find a way to do it in PHP?  Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT  
    f.orderID as fOrderID,
    f.typeID as fTypeId,
    f.solarSystemID as fSystemId,
    f.regionID as fRegionId,
    f.price as fPrice,
    f.volRemaining as fVolRemain,
    f.bid as fBid,
    f.reportedTime as fReportedTime,
    t.orderID as tOrderID,
    t.typeID as tTypeId, 
    t.solarSystemID as tSystemId,
    t.regionID as tRegionId,
    t.price as tPrice,
    t.volRemaining as tVolRemain,
    t.bid as tBid,
    if(((f.volRemaining < t.volRemaining)),
      ((f.volRemaining * t.price) - (f.price * f.volRemaining)), 
      ((t.volRemaining * t.Price) - (f.price * t.volRemaining))) as profit,
    t.reportedTime as tReporedtTime
    FROM marketData as f
    JOIN marketData as t on t.typeID = f.typeID 
    WHERE f.regionID = 10000001
    AND t.regionID = 10000030
    AND f.bid = 0
    AND t.bid = 1
    GROUP BY f.orderID
    HAVING profit > 1000000
    ORDER BY profit DESC
    LIMIT 100
```

MarketDB Layout(doesn't include 9 additional columns that I'm not using right now):

```
prim-unique                        indexed
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| orderID | regionID | stationID | typeID | bid | price |
+-------------------------------------------------------+ 
| 12345   |  223344  |  334455   |  13    |  0  | 22.43 |
| 12543   |  298474  |  348993   |  13    |  1  | 24.55 |   
| 24574   |  273646  |  392273   |  13    |  0  | 19.32 |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

EDITED:
ADDED EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type  table   type    possible_keys    key    key_len  ref              rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE       f       ALL     typeID           NULL   NULL     NULL             761338  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE       t       ref     typeID           typeID 8        market.f.typeID  76      Using where
```

Comment: Add an `explain` before the select so it looks like this: `explain select...` and post the results.

Comment: RegionID should have an index on it.

Comment: Ryan: I added the explain to my post.

Comment: Adder: I did have the regionID indexed before.  I can add it again to see how it goes.

Comment: Adder: I added the index to regionID and the query takes the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the table should have 2 indexes.  One index that includes (regionID,bid,typeID), probably in that order, and a second index that just has (typeID).  The first index will be used to quickly scan f for records that match the criteria and retrieve the typeID (it's in the index).  The second index, will be used on t for the join.  I'm not sure why it doesn't use the larger index to include the where clause at the same time, but it could change with a later version of MySQL.

Depending on your actual data patterns, you might be able to tweak the first index a little more by creating multiple variations of it at the same time, that just try the 6 different possible orders, and run an explain plan to see which index is used.  Then simply drop the unused indexes.

Note 1:
Having the two indexes will slow down your inserts and deletes on the table, but I would expect the speed of this join query to be a bigger issue, especially without the indexes.

Note 2:
Reducing the number of columns in the table will also help slightly, but does not address the scaling issue with a join.

Comment: Wow, that dropped the query down to .33/seconds.  I have some more queries with additional joins from other tables so I'll play around with the indexes to see if I can drop it further but they are MUCH better than what they were before.  Didn't know you were able to group indexes.  Any suggestions with speeding up the inserts or will I just have to deal with the slower speed?  I plan to have data fed into my DB 24/7.

Comment: There's no way to avoid overhead from indexes, except to have fewer indexes or index fewer columns.  I don't know too much about speeding up the inserts, but you can check the MySQL docs (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-speed.html).  Make sure you switch to the correct version of MySQL.

If the data doesn't need to be persistent (stored between reboots), then you can also look at the memory database engine.